# Различная реакция на переопределение идентификатора в браузерах Opera и Firefox

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Как объяснить различную реакцию на выполнение следующего кода в разных браузерах?

```
var func = function() { console.log('1'); };
function func() { console.log('2'); }
func();
```

При выполнении в Opera 36.0.2130.32 выдается ошибка:

> "SyntaxError: Identifier 'func' has already been declared at
>   https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.11.min.js:1:13891 at
>   https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.11.min.js:1:10820"

При выполнении в Firefox 44.0.2 ошибка не выдается, и в консоль выводится значение "2".
Вот ссылка на jsbin: https://jsbin.com/hijobojawe/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Видимо firefox берёт последнюю реализованную функцию с данным названием, пропуская все предыдущие определения, а другие браузеры не могут это просто так оставить.

Comment: Различная реакция браузеров - нормальное поведение в настоящее (да и в прошлое) время. Точнее - не нормальное поведение, но такое вполне бывает. Не все бразузеры точно выполняют стандарты.

Comment: Хороший ответ дал @Олег Дёгтев.

Comment: Странное дело: в консольн на JS Bin мой FF 45 выводит "2", в то же время, этот же код в ScratchPad в консоль FireBug выводит "1".

Comment: Странное дело-2: если обернуть всё в ф-ю, то и JS Bin [начинает показывать "1"](https://jsbin.com/kacesogayo/edit?js,console,output) там, где раньше показывал "2" (консоли JS Bin), в том же FireFox. В общем, на JSBin лучше не смотреть и проверять в «родных» консолях браузеров.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хорошая демонстрация неочевидного момента т.н. ["var hoisting"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). Дело в том, что на стадии инициализации все объявления переменных, которые могут быть где угодно в теле функции, перемещаются наверх, в то время, как их назначение остаётся на месте.

**Было:**

```
function x(){
  // ..здесь много кода
  var v = 'test'; // внезапно объявляем ещё одну переменную
  // ..здесь дальше код
  function f(){ /* тело ф-ии */ } // объявили функцию
}
```

**Стало:**

```
function x(){
  function f(){ /* тело ф-ии */ } // объявили функцию
  var v;
  // ..здесь много кода
  var v = 'test'; // внезапно объявляем ещё одну переменную
  // ..здесь дальше код
}
```

Объявления функций так же могут находиться где-то ниже по коду внутри контекста, и при этом тоже «переезжают» вверх при исполнении. Причём, как [пишут](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/) некоторые источники, становятся **до** объявления всех переменных.

Сначала `function`, потом `var`, потом `v = 'test'`.

В вашем суперпримере ещё один вопрос: какое объявление `function()` сработает раньше – в правой части назначения переменной, или самостоятельное. Раньше сработает самостоятельное – function declaration. Назначение `func = function(){..}` выполнится в последнюю очередь.

Итак, сначала объявляется ф-я с `2`, затем объявляется переменная `func` (и вызывает ошибку, т.к. с таким именем уже есть ф-я), а потом эта переменная получает значение ф-ии с `1`. По-моему, это правильная реализация JS стандартов.

**Тесты:**

- FireFox 45.0.1, ScratchPad, консоль FireBug:  "1"
- Chrome 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit), `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'func' has already been declared`
- Safari 9.1 (11601.5.17.1), консоль: 1
- Opera 34.0, консоль: 1
- Opera 36.0, консоль: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'func' has already been declared`

Comment: что примечательно, если этот код поместить в функцию - `Uncaught SyntaxError` не будет, по крайней мере в хроме, и выведет `1`

Comment: Точки над i расставит `"use strict";` : )

Comment: это да :-) но я думал по умолчанию он отключен в консоли.

Comment: Хотя нет, не помог `use strict` - ошибки нет - и по прежнему выводит `1` :)

Comment: тоже попробовал с обёрткой в ф-ю и "use strict" в FF и Chrome – никаких Warning'ов. Чудеса..

Comment: Похоже при запуске напрямую в консоли используется какое-то другое окружение, нужно попробовать в подключаемом файле в функции и без

Comment: В консоли используется что-то стиктоподобное, но не совсем.

Answer (score 5):

Я так понимаю, что должно быть вообще "1". В моем ИЕ как раз выводится единица.
Что тут происходит? При выполнении скрипта существует 2 стадии. Стадия инициализации и стадия выполнения. Function Declaration (2 строка) происходит на стадии инициализации. Далее по-ходу выполнения скрипта - тело функции переписывается в function expression (1 строка), которые как раз выполняются на стадии выполнения. В итоге мы должны видеть (И видим в ИЕ) единицу.
А то, что мы видим на практике - видимо различия реализации JS движков, у каждого производителя он свой. Мы видим, что Opera(и Хром) не дают переписать объявленную функцию. Firefox просто игнорирует перезапись, а IE спокойно перезаписывает.
[Почитать.](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression)